# Downloading files in Skype and Firefox stops Audacious under Gnome

Tags: gnome, firefox, skype

Strangely, when someone sends me a file on Skype and I click to open it, my music player Audacious stops playing and the playlist gets messed up (some random mp3s appear inside) and the file on skype doesn't get opened. The same happens when I download a file in Firefox. How can I fix this?

I use Arch Linux 3.12.7-2-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT x86_64 GNU/Linux with GNOME Shell 3.10.2.1, audacious 3.4.3 and Skype 4.2.0.11.

Comment: What file? It happens with all files or just some?

Comment: I think with all files.